# Regex : remove first 0 if second digit of the string is not a 0

Tags: regex, phone-number

I have to clean up with Regex phone numbers. 
Sometimes i get phone number starting with 0, in this case i wan t to keep the rest of the chain:

- Ex.: 0666777888 --> 666777888

For international numbers i would expect:

- Ex.: 00034666777888 --> 0034666777888

but my issue is that, the expression should not change anything for correct-international number (starting with 00)

- Ex.: 0034666777888 --> 0034666777888

the rule which would always work would be:
in case the string start with 1 or 3 '0' then remove the first '0' otherwise keep the string as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Use `^0(?!0)` as pattern.

Python example:

```
>>> re.sub(r'^(?!00[^0])0', '', '0666777888')
'666777888'
>>> re.sub(r'^(?!00[^0])0', '', '00034666777888')
'0034666777888'
>>> re.sub(r'^(?!00[^0])0', '', '0034666777888')
'0034666777888'
```

Javascript:

```
> '0666777888'.replace(/^(?!00[^0])0/, '')
'666777888'
> '00034666777888'.replace(/^(?!00[^0])0/, '')
'0034666777888'
> '0034666777888'.replace(/^(?!00[^0])0/, '')
'0034666777888'
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not work as it does not remove the first 0 in case there are 3 consecutives: 00034666777888 -> 0034666777888

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex if the language you use supports negative lookaheads:

```
^(?!00[1-9])0
```

And replace by nothing.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/kJ5aU7)

---

As per comment, to remove the quotes if present, you can use:

```
^"?(?:(?!00[1-9])0([0-9]+)|(00[0-9]+))"?$
```

And replace with `$1$2`. (or `\1\2` depending on the language/engine)

[reex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/jU4lG4)

---

### Explanation

```
^                     // Matches beginning of line
   "?                 // Matches opening double quotes if present
      (?:             // Begin of non-capture group
          (?!00[1-9]  // Prevents the match of two zeroes followed by a digit other than zero
          0           // Matches 0
          ([0-9]+)    // Matches all the digits after 0 and store in first capture group
      |               // Or...
          (00[0-9]+)  // Two zeroes followed by any number of digits in second capture group
      )               // End of non-capture group
   "?                 // Matches closing double quotes if present
$                     // Matches end of line
```

Comment: Thanks that Works but i need to admit that i do not understand.

Comment: as on top of that rule i would like to remove the " which may surround the string. ex. "0666333777" --> 666333777. I tried with such RegEx: ^\"?(?!00[1-9])0\"? but it does not remove the last "

Comment: @FredericRIsch I updated my answer for the quotes and included a short description. If you have questions, I'm still around :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. your new code is almost working, as the quotas are removed ... only if the RegEx removes the 0, otherwise no.  http://regex101.com/r/qI1aU9

Comment: @FredericRIsch Do you mean for `0034666777888`? Oh, okay, you can use this regex for all the cases: `^"?(?:(?!00[1-9])0([0-9]+)|(00[0-9]+))"?$` see [link](http://regex101.com/r/jU4lG4).

Answer (score 1):

Java version:

```
System.out.println("034666777888".replaceAll("^0(?!0[1-9]+)([0-9]*)","$1"));
System.out.println("00034666777888".replaceAll("^0(?!0[1-9]+)([0-9]*)","$1"));
System.out.println("0034666777888".replaceAll("^0(?!0[1-9]+)([0-9]*)","$1"));
```

outputs:

```
34666777888
0034666777888
0034666777888
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not work as it does not remove the first 0 in case there are 3 consecutives: 00034666777888 -> 0034666777888

Answer (score 1):

I think this regexp should help you:

```
(?=0*)(00)*([1-9][\d]*)
```

Replace the match with: \1\2